# Import table from website with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to import a table from a website and afterwards transform the data into a pandas dataframe.

The website is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M

Thats my code so far:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

website_url = requests.get(
'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M').text 

soup = BeautifulSoup(website_url,'lxml')

My_table = soup.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'})

for x in soup.find_all('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable'}):
    table = x.text


print(My_table)
print(table)
```

[Output of print(My_table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzW7o.jpg)

[Output of print(table)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo4g6.jpg)

How do I convert this webpage table to a panda dataframe?
[panda dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sj8t.png)

Comment: Answered here in terms of read_html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55566117/i-have-some-problems-with-data-cleaning/55566486#55566486 Not sure whether that makes it a duplicate as you just want table. First part of solution will still work for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
pd.read_html()
```

?

Also, since the table is very standard, why not directly copy the table into excel and import it as DataFrame?

Comment: Hey Gen, thnx for your answer. read_html() helped a lot but for some reason it does not contain the Neighbourhood column

Comment: pd.read_html(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M',match = 'Neighbourhood')

Comment: Strange, same result for me:
df = pd.read_html(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M',match= 'Neighbourhood')
print(df)

Comment: got it, thank you! df = pd.read_html(r'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_postal_codes_of_Canada:_M',match= 'Neighbourhood')
type(df)
len(df)
df = df[0]
df