# Set Value based on Condition and position

Tags: python, pandas

I need to set the value of a column based on a condition, but I only need to set it on the first 5 rows.

This is my statement for selecting the correct rows which works fine.

```
kunden_df.loc[kunden_df["Distanz"] == 1].iloc[0:amount_contracts]
```

However setting the value on the column (Betreuer) does not do a thing.

```
kunden_df.loc[kunden_df["Distanz"] == 1].iloc[0:amount_contracts]["Betreuer"] = value
```

I know this is a syntax problem and I have already found quite similar questions (like: [Pandas/Python: Set value of one column based on value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161120/pandas-python-set-value-of-one-column-based-on-value-in-another-column)) , but I cant make it work. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to determine the indices of the rows you want to change and then set the new value with pandas [at](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) function using these indices

For example:

```
idx = kunden_df.loc[kunden_df["Distanz"] == 1].iloc[0:amount_contracts].index.values

kunden_df.at[idx, 'Betreuer'] = value
```