# How can I get calculate buy and sell quantity in pandas?

Tags: pandas, cumulative-sum

[image: picture]

When I have data of quantity and buy and sell program, I want to get the cumulative quantity by adding a number when it is 'buy' and deducting a number when it is 'sell'. How can I do this in pandas? I know there is .cumsum() function to add it, but I don't know how to deduct it.

Comment: Can you add the data snippet as code rather than an image so that people have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to work with

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161189/874188 for a start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flip the integer when selling:

```
df['quantity'].where(df['buy&sell'].eq('buy'), -df['quantity']).cumsum()
```