# How do I make an if statement in with multiple parameter using excel columns in python csv

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, multiple-columns

So basically I am trying to write a statement where if a value in Col1 = 1 or Col2 = 1 than create a new column with the value 10 and if both Col1 and Col2 = 0 the new column should print 0 or just skip.

so far this is what I did

```
if df.Col1 == 1 or df.Col2 == 1:
    df['newCol'] = 10
else: pass
```

This is giving me an error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas/Python: Set value of one column based on value in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49161120/pandas-python-set-value-of-one-column-based-on-value-in-another-column)

Comment: the thing is this is based on one parameter. I want to make an statement that satisfy both parameters

Comment: It's the same syntax you just use an `OR` operator (`|`) in your condition (the first parameter in the `where` method. The real take-away is that anytime you are in a dataframe and you think "I need to loop" it should throw red flags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df['newCol'] = np.where(((df['Col1']==1)|(df['Col2']==1)), 10,np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this assuming df is your dataframe.. df['newcolumn'] =df.apply(function, axis=1)  then in function write   def function(row) :  if row['col1'] == 1 or row['Col2'] == 1:
return 10        (you can pass 0 in else part as well)