# Get new dataframe value based on multiple conditions from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose the following dataframe:

```
   c1  c2
0  0   "phrase_x 12"
1  0   "phrase_y 34"
2  1   "phrase_x 56"  
3  1   "phrase_y 78"
```

I want to make four new columns, c3-c6, based on conditions from c1 and c2, such that:

- if c1 == 0 and c2 contains phrase_x, c3 is filled with data from c2, split with a separator string
- if c1 == 0 and c2 contains phrase_y, c4 is filled with data from c2, split with a separator string
- if c1 == 1 and c2 contains phrase_x, c5 is filled with data from c2, split with a separator string
- if c1 == 1 and c2 contains phrase_y, c6 is filled with data from c2, split with a separator string
- The empty cells may be filled with NaN

Something like this:

```
   c1  c2             c3    c4    c5    c6
0  0   "phrase_x 12"  12    NaN   NaN   NaN
1  0   "phrase_y 34"  NaN   34    NaN   NaN
2  1   "phrase_x 56"  NaN   NaN   56    NaN
3  1   "phrase_y 78"  NaN   NaN   NaN   78
```

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49161313/21420031), which helped me further a bit, but only if I want to use 1 condition, like this:

`df.loc[df['c2'].str.contains("phrase_x") , 'c3'] = df['c2'].str.split('-> ').str[1]`
`df.loc[df['c2'].str.contains("phrase_y") , 'c4'] = df['c2'].str.split('-> ').str[1]`

This code produces

```
   c1  c2             c3    c4    
0  0   "phrase_x 12"  12    NaN
1  0   "phrase_y 34"  NaN   34 
2  1   "phrase_x 56"  56    NaN
3  1   "phrase_y 78"  NaN   78
```

Is there a way to use loc with multiple conditions? It seems to me that a possibility is to first use the above 2 statements, and then copy the data over based on if c1 is 0 or 1, like this:

```
df.loc[df['c1'] = 1, 'c5'] = df['c3']
df.loc[df['c1'] = 1, 'c6'] = df['c4']
```

However this seems tedious, and you would also need to delete the data in the previous columns.

I also tried the [solution](https://ValueError:%20Cannot%20set%20a%20DataFrame%20with%20multiple%20columns%20to%20the%20single%20column%20Budget%20Outlet%201) under the previous mentioned one, with np.where():

```
df['c3'] = df.where(df['c1'] == 0 & df['c2'].str.contains("phrase_x"), df['c2'].str.split('-> ').str[1], axis = 0)
```

However this only leads to more errors, e.g.

`ValueError: Cannot set a DataFrame with multiple columns to the single column Budget Outlet 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution should be changed by chain both mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m1 = df['c2'].str.contains("phrase_x")
m2 = df['c2'].str.contains("phrase_y")

m3 = df['c1'].eq(0)
m4 = df['c1'].eq(1)

s = df['c2'].str.split().str[1] 

df.loc[m1 & m3 ,'c3'] = s
df.loc[m2 & m3, 'c4'] = s

df.loc[m1 & m4 ,'c5'] = s
df.loc[m2 & m4, 'c6'] = s

print (df)
   c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6
0   0  phrase_x 12   12  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   0  phrase_y 34  NaN   34  NaN  NaN
2   1  phrase_x 56  NaN  NaN   56  NaN
3   1  phrase_y 78  NaN  NaN  NaN   78
```

Another idea is create tuples for dynamic solution:

```
tups = [('phrase_x',0,'c3'),
        ('phrase_y',0,'c4'),
        ('phrase_x',1,'c5'),
        ('phrase_y',1,'c6')]

s = df['c2'].str.split().str[1] 

for (c2, c1, cols) in tups:
    df.loc[df['c2'].str.contains(c2) & df['c1'].eq(c1), cols] = s

print (df)
   c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6
0   0  phrase_x 12   12  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   0  phrase_y 34  NaN   34  NaN  NaN
2   1  phrase_x 56  NaN  NaN   56  NaN
3   1  phrase_y 78  NaN  NaN  NaN   78
```

---

General solution if need assign each row to new column is:

```
df1 = df.join(df.assign(cols = [f'c{x+3}' for x in range(len(df))],
               vals = df['c2'].str.split().str[1] )
             .pivot(columns='cols', values='vals'))
print (df1)
   c1           c2   c3   c4   c5   c6
0   0  phrase_x 12   12  NaN  NaN  NaN
1   0  phrase_y 34  NaN   34  NaN  NaN
2   1  phrase_x 56  NaN  NaN   56  NaN
3   1  phrase_y 78  NaN  NaN  NaN   78
```

Comment: Thanks! I found this the most helpful answer, especially the first part, really clear layout of the conditions. However, I am not quite sure what you mean by "chain both mask by `&` for bitwise `AND`". Could you clarify?

Comment: @MrTomatosoup - Sure, it means need apply one condition and another one togehter by AND operator, here working with arrays so is used `&` for bitwise AND.

Answer (score 1):

Everything will be easier if you split your `c2` to two columns then apply condition. That's make your code simpler. Here is what I mean:

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[0,0,1,1],
                   'c2':['x','y','x','y'],
                   'val':[12,34,56,78]})
```

Simple using `loop`, with `zip`:

```
for i,j,k in zip(df['c1'].tolist(), df['c2'].tolist(), [3,4,5,6]):
    df[f'c{k}'] = np.where((df['c1']==i) & (df['c2']==j), df['val'], np.NaN)
```

I am don't know your actual data looks like so I use df['c1/2'].tolist() here. **However, you should not use this** but to modify ur code, creating your desired pair of list of conditions from your `c1` and `c2`

Which should give you desired output:

```
   c1 c2  val    c3    c4    c5    c6
0   0  x   12  12.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   0  y   34   NaN  34.0   NaN   NaN
2   1  x   56   NaN   NaN  56.0   NaN
3   1  y   78   NaN   NaN   NaN  78.0
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you are doing in the for loop?  isn't loopwise iteration over a dataframe generally a bad idea?

Comment: @MrTomatosoup: this is not iterating over rows.
What I am doing is to iterate over your condition. You have 4 different types of condition, and I iterate over 4 condition; each condition create a new column

Answer (score 0):

Split the columns `c2` into two columns as suggested by one of our fellow above is a good idea. Here is improve code you can use

Generate the unique combination of the two

```
l1 = df['c1'].unique()
l2 = df['c2'].unique()
combin = [(v1, v2) for v1 in l1 for v2 in l2]
```

Then creating a loop over like above:

```
for k, (i,j) in enumerate(combin):
    df[f'c{k+3}'] = np.where((df['c1']==i) & (df['c2']==j), df['val'], np.NaN)
```

Should giving your expected result

Comment: Wouldn't loopwise iteration over the full dataframe be a bad idea? (Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/21420031)